# How to get data out of esModule function instead of flat function?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, angular5, es6-modules

So I am currently using require to get all of the TS files that represent one of my components so that I have them to use as a reference.

```
this.req = require.context('../../my/context', true, /^\.\/.*\.component.ts$/)
```

I also have a function as part of my service called "getComponent" that I am then I am using a passed file path to get the required component from `req`.

```
const component = this.req(filePath);
```

At this point if I log this in the console, I see an object that has the function and all of its associated data. It looks like this:

[image: Object in Console]

However, if I try to access this information programmatically, I of course simply get a reference to the function itself back:

[image: Function reference in console]

Is there any way I can access the data in the first state programmatically without getting back a reference to the function instead?

Comment: What “data” in the first example isn’t present in the second?

Comment: All of it? I am looking to get access to the `arguments`, `caller`, `length`, `__annotations__` etc. properties, which do not exist within the function itself.

Comment: Does `component.arguments` not work for you? (*Note that you should [never access `caller` on a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller)*). If this is just an issue of the console not rendering the `function`’s members, wrap it in an object like this: `console.log({component})`

Comment: Yes it does, feel free to put that in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an artefact of how Chrome optimises its console messages.

When the object passed to `console.log()` is just a function, the output is just a simplified view of that function:

```js
function myFunc() {}
console.log(myFunc);
```

> ```
> ƒ myFunc() {}
> ```

If you really need to see the guts of the `function` object, wrap it in a new object:

```js
console.log({ myFunc });
```

> ```
> {myFunc: ƒ}
>   myFunc: ƒ myFunc()
>   arguments: null
>   caller: null
>   length: 0
>   name: "myFunc"
>   prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
>   __proto__: ƒ ()
>   [[FunctionLocation]]: VM14940:1
>   [[Scopes]]: Scopes[1]
> __proto__: Object
> ```